# android camera save file error

Tags: android, camera

I'm developing an android application based on camera function. I got some trouble in my program which I cannot figure it out. My `mCurrentImagePath` is always null as it is initialized. The logcat shows that it never hits the `takepicture()` function, so it is never given a value. I tried to let the thread sleep so that the later operation to bitmap can wait until the camera save the picture well, but it is still not working. But if I don't read the picture I took, the application works perfect, it can save the picture well. I also tried to use `bitmapfactory.decodebyte()` to directly operate on the meta data, but it failed, too. Anyone can give me any idea about which part I got wrong? That would be really helpful. Thank you very much!!!

```
private static final String IMAGE_DIRECTORY ="sdcard/DCIM/Camera";
public static String mCurrentImagePath = null;
private CameraView cv;
private Camera mCamera = null;

public Camera.PictureCallback pictureCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback() {

    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

        try{
            isFinish = false;
            long timeTaken = System.currentTimeMillis();
            mCurrentImagePath = IMAGE_DIRECTORY + "/"+ createName(timeTaken) + ".jpg";
            File file = new File(mCurrentImagePath);
            Log.d("path", "mCurrentImagePath_takepicture = " + mCurrentImagePath);
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            fos.write(data);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
            Toast.makeText(OpenASURF.this, "saving the picture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            isFinish = true;
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mCamera.startPreview();
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}; 

cv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(mCamera != null) {
            mCamera.takePicture(null, null, pictureCallback);
            // let the system wait until finish taking the pictures.
            //while(isFinish == false) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(20000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //}
            Log.d("path", "mCurrentImagePath_over1 = " + mCurrentImagePath);
            Bitmap bmp = null;

            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentImagePath);
            Log.d("path", "mCurrentImagePath_over2 = " + mCurrentImagePath);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No matter how long you wait after `takePicture()`, the `onPictureTaken()` callback will be called only after your `OnClick()` returns: they all use the app Main thread.

You can call

```
BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentImagePath);
```

in your `onPictureTaken()`, or you may post an event from `onPictureTaken()` to your activity.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, it really brights my mind of this problem. I've tried to add my calculation part into onPictureTaken(), but it also shows an OutofMemoryError. Do you have any idea about it?

Comment: I will use the picture I take from camera for image recognition. I will calculate its SURF descriptor for further matching.

Comment: I mean - what you do to get outOfMemory? What do you see in log? But this is probably worth a question of its own.

Comment: I've finished the application, thank you for your help, I use a AsynTask for backend calculation which works perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Is `IMAGE_DIRECTORY` correct? I'd expect it to be `/sdcard/DCIM/Camera`, with the opening forward slash.

Better yet would be to get the image path the right way: [DIRECTORY_PICTURES](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#saving-media)

```
File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
File file = new File(path, "DemoPicture.jpg");
```